# WCF REST service not responding and issuing 500 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, rest, wcf

I tried creating a WCF REST service in our existing ASP.NET application. However, when I try to browse to my service using the web browser, it says "This site can't be reached".

The URL I'm trying to hit is: http://localhost:81/ExternalServices/WS/Snap/REST/SnapService.svc

Also, when I try hitting it using a client tool, it gives me error 500.

```
// SnapService.svc
<% @ServiceHost Service = "DomainName.ProjectName.WebApp.ExternalServices.WS.Snap.REST.SnapService" Language="C#" %>

// ISnapService.cs
namespace DomainName.ProjectName.WebApp.ExternalServices.WS.Snap.REST
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ISnapService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UpdateLender")]
        string UpdateLender(string userName, string password, string portfolioCode, string xmlRequest);
    }
}

// SnapService.cs
namespace DomainName.ProjectName.WebApp.ExternalServices.WS.Snap.REST
{
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class SnapService : ISnapService
    {
        public string UpdateLender(string userName, string password, string portfolioCode, string xmlRequest)
        {
            // implementation here
            return SnapServiceHelper.UpdateLender(userName, password, portfolioCode, xmlRequest);
        }
    }
}

// Web.config
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="DomainName.ProjectName.WebApp.ExternalServices.WS.Snap.REST.SnapService" behaviorConfiguration="defaultBehaviour">
        <endpoint name="webHttpsBinding" address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="DomainName.ProjectName.WebApp.ExternalServices.WS.Snap.REST.ISnapService" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" bindingConfiguration="webHttpTransportSecurity"/>
        <endpoint name="mexHttpsBinding" address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpTransportSecurity">
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttp">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="defaultBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**EDIT:** Enabled debugging to write to a log file. Here's the exception I get when I attempt to browse to the link above:

Operation 'UpdateLender' of contract 'ISnapService' specifies multiple request body parameters to be serialized without any wrapper elements. At most one body parameter can be serialized without wrapper elements. Either remove the extra body parameters or set the BodyStyle property on the WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute to Wrapped.

Comment: What's the detailed error you get?

Comment: The error message from the client tool is: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. It happens when I call response.GetResponseStream(). When I try to use Postman and use the url: http://localhost:81/ExternalServices/WS/Snap/REST/SnapService.svc the error message is: 500 System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException (a generic message)

Comment: Check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731053(v=vs.110).aspx